# How are JNDI names determined?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jndi, resin

I have an EJB defined as:

```
@Stateless(name="articleController")
public class ArticleController {
   ...
}
```

I'm using the Jersey JAX-RS v2.4 api to define a REST service:

```
@Path("article")
public class ArticleService extends BaseService {

    @PUT
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String insertArticle() throws NamingException {
        ArticleController controller;

        controller = (ArticleController)ctx.lookup("java:app/webapp/articleController");
        controller.addArticle();

        return(controller.getCurrentDate());
    }   
}
```

I'm using the resin 4.0.36 server.  It's using EJB lite 3.1.  This code above all works fine.  I can retrieve an EJB by context lookup.  Another example is in persistence.xml.  I have the data source defined in resin:

```
<non-jta-data-source>java:/comp/env/jdbc/tehdb</non-jta-data-source>
```

with resin.xml:

```
<database jndi-name="jdbc/tehdb">
    <driver type="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver">
        ...
    </driver>
</database>
```

My questions are:

Why is my JNDI name *"java:app/webapp/articleController"* and not just *"articleController"* on the lookup?  Why is my data source *"java:/comp/env/jdbc/tehdb"* and not just *"jdbc/tehdb"*?  I see many examples that just show the JNDI name as the later.  How are these JNDI names determined in a Resin managed object?  I don't understand where these are created.  If I use the later names, I get naming exceptions and failures.

I ultimately wrote a function that would dump out the whole context tree so that I could determine the path names, but I think that I may be doing something wrong.